# How to search in Elastic by post title/concerpt/content?

Tags: search

Im trying to make Wordpress to search in Elastic by some restriction:

```
$args['ep_integrate'] = true;

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    // what to write here to search in "title", "excerpt", "content" only?
});

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I was tryting to modify the query:

```
$args['ep_integrate'] = true;

add_action('posts_where', function($where) {
    return ' posts.ID = 234234';
    // return ' post_title LIKE "%paff%" OR post_contents LIKE "%paff%" OR post_excerpt LIKE "%paff%";
}, 10,2);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

but its like I didnt set anything, it still returns bunch of result instead of one.

Comment: I see you are using `WP_Query` and WordPress by default searches the post title, excerpt and content when the `s` parameter is specified..

Comment: then again, it returns tons of irrelevant results

Comment: Try asking/searching on the Elastic's forums/site. Questions specific to 3rd party plugins like Elastic are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

`posts_where` is a filter, not an action. Also you should concatenate your modification with the query and return `$where`. Look at the [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where).

Comment: oh, right, but even if I do it as "filter" still no work